# Insert data from text file into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have files on my server example 25295.txt, 24565.txt on my server where file name is the user id  and the content of the file is like

```
[{"name":"+91 88264 73159","mobile":"+918826473159"},
 {"name":"+91 99971 17220","mobile":"+919997117220"}]
```

My table structure is like this:

[image]

I want to run a cron job to insert each name and mobile with `user_id` (name of the text file is user id) in different rows from multiple files. There are around 800 records for the same in each file and also trim the mobile with:

```
$mobile=str_replace('+','0',$data['mobile']);
$mobile=str_replace(' ','',$mobile);
$mobile=substr($mobile, -10);
```

How to do the same and after the upload I want to delete the text file from the server.

Comment: this method also works fine but it does not take user_id from file  name and how to use it for multiple files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you have on your server look like JSON. You can simply decode them and then insert them as you would normally do.

```
$filePath = '/tmp/somefile.txt';
$contents = file_get_contents($filePath);
$obj = json_decode($contents);

var_dump($cbj);
```

### Update

To make it even easier, here's a little example of the whole process from file to database.

#### cronjob.php

```
// Make your database connection
$link = mysqli_connect('<hostname>', '<username>', '<password>', '<database>');

// Define the file location
$fileLocation = '/tmp/example.txt';

// Retrieve contents
$contents = file_get_contents($fileLocation);

// Convert json to ObjectArray
$persons = json_decode($contents);

// Loop through array and insert
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $number = substr(str_replace(' ', '', str_replace('+', '00', $person->number))), -10);
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO persons (id, name, number) VALUES ('".$person->id."', '".$person->name."', '".$number."')";

    mysqli_query($link, $stmt);
}

// Remove the file
unlink($fileLocation);
```

#### example.txt

```
[{"id":14,"name":"John","number":"555-66-77-8"},{"id":24,"name":"Jane","number":"555-77-88-9"},{"id":34,"name":"Santa","number":"555-6-77-77"}]
```

Comment: $obj[0]['mobile'],  $obj[1]['mobile'], ... like wise you can get all datas

Answer (score 0):

My code is for one file say  `25295.txt`

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','password','dbname');
if($conn){
$filename = '25295.txt';
$filePath = '/path_to_file/'.$filename;// file path    
$contents = file_get_contents($filePath);
$userID = rtrim($filename,".txt");// this will give  25295  
$data = json_decode($contents,true);// this will give associative array 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name(user_id,name, mobile) VALUES(?,?, ?)") or die($stmt->error);
foreach($data as $insertRow){
    foreach($insertRow as $key => $value){
    $insertData[$key] =  $value;
     }  
    extract($insertData);// this will give variable from array with name same as key of array
    $stmt->bind_param('iss',$userID,$name,$mobile);
    $stmt->execute();   
}   
}
```